# How to Remove HTML element by class name

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing

I'm changing a database using phpmyadmin with several html pages inside it and I would like to remove, from all these pages, all the `<div>` and other tags that contain a certain `class` or `id`.

Example:

Case 1

```
<div class="undesirable">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col1"></div> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Case 2

```
<div class="undesirable">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col1"></div>
      <div class="col2"></div> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i would like to remove all `<div>` that contain the `class="undesirable"`. In some cases, there is still the possibility of appearing as `class="pre_undesirable"`, or something similar.

Initially I thought of using `regex`, but as there are variations in htmls, code breaks are occurring, as there is no way to know when the `<\div>` will end.
Possibly the answer would be HTML parser, but I can't understand how to use it. Any indication of where to start?

Comment: "I'm changing a database using phpmyadmin with several html pages inside it and I would like to remove" — Are you asking how to do this with SQL?

Comment: php code pls, also pls state in the tags that this is a php related query

Comment: I would like a direction, it could be sql, java, or even the possibility of being regex. Turns out I don't even know where to start. As for the php code, the column in question corresponds only to the html code requested in a "blank" theme in wordpress, later requested by iframe on another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dealing with html, you probably should use an html parser and search for the removal target using xpath. To demonstrate, I'll change your html a bit:

```
$original= 
'<html><body>
<div class="undesirable">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col1"></div> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="keepme">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col1"></div>
      <div class="col2"></div> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="pre_undesirable">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col1"></div>
      <div class="col2"></div> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="keepme">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col1"></div>
      <div class="col2"></div> 
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
';
$HTMLDoc = new DOMDocument();
$HTMLDoc->loadHTML($original);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($HTMLDoc);

$targets = $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"undesirable")]');
foreach($targets as $target){
        $target->parentNode->removeChild($target);
}
echo $HTMLDoc->saveHTML();
```

The output should include only the two "keep me" `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

We can make use D3JS to remove or append any the HTML elements by class name or id.
We can make use of Select() and Selectall() for the selection of the particular elements in the HTML. Incase if we want to append any div tag use append('div') to insert the div for the data.

```
<script>
      function remove() 
         {
        d3.select(.undesirable)
          .selectAll("li")
          .exit()
          .remove()
         }

</script>
```